# Build Failure Analyzer - General Understanding

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am wondering whether it is possible to have an general rule for ny kind of errors matching "*error*" and in addition some specific rules matching "known" issues as "[ERROR] some error message".

So the intention is, that either the specific rule matches and if not, then at least the general.
But it would also be sufficient, if both rules will be displayed.

Thanks,
A

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is your expected output ? Could you show a sample input as well ?

Comment: Solved for me - THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I received an answer from the developers of the Build Failure Analyzer:

It is possible to have two causes that catches the same log line and they would both be displayed.
Furthermore the is an possibility to customize the message that gets displayed if there are no causes found on the Jenkins system config page.